# How to enforce constructor signature across sub-classes?

Tags: object, oop, inheritance, abap

I want to dynamically instantiate **sub-classes** of a given class, and I need a **consistent signature** for the sub-classes' **constructors** to avoid errors at runtime.

Constructors can be defined with arbitrary sets of parameters in each sub-class since constructors are not redefinitions. This can cause problems during dynamic instantiation if a sub-class defines a *constructor with a different signature*.

I need a dynamic sub-class instantiation because the logic itself to select the appropriate sub-class is dynamic. However, that logic is external in a relation to the instantiated classes.

Instead of defining a public `constructor`, I thought of defining a public static method `create` that would enforce the signature and return an instance of itself. However, *static methods cannot be redefined* in sub-classes.

Is there a way to enforce a consistent dynamic instantiation of sub-classes ?

Comment: I wonder if I understand it properly: There is a superclass, which has several subclasses and you want to create an instance of one of the subclasses dynamically. As method definitions cannot be changed in a subclass in ABAP, I don't see any problem here with the signature (or do I miss something?). The signature of the constructor will be the same in each subclass. What you need is a factory class to create the necessary instance.

Comment: Constructors of sub-classes can be defined with different signatures from its base class (they are not redefinitions). So a sub-class can be defined later (that I do not know of at the time of my implementation of the base class) with a specific constructor signature and that will make dynamic instantiation fail.

Comment: You mean, there is no constructor in the parent class, but each subclass has its own constructor with different signatures?

Comment: At the moment there are constructors in the base class and every sub-class, and they all have an identical signature. However nothing prevents a programmer from defining his own sub-class in the future with a constructor having a different signature. That would make dynamic instantiation fail (as the set of passed parameters would not be appropriate). I want to prevent this kind of error.

Comment: If I try to redefine a constructor in a subclass, I get an error message, that this is not possible, it also in the SAPHelp: "An instance constructor cannot be redefined.". Do I miss here something?

Comment: Yes, constructors cannot be redefined. But they can be defined in every sub-class with their own set of parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of a way to prevent people inheriting from a class from creating an own constructor with different parameters.

But what you can do is to not give the constructor any parameters, and have a separate method "initialize" instead. That method would then always get called by your framework after creating the object. That method can then be part of an interface those classes need to implement or an `ABSTRACT` method of the base-class they need to redefine. Which means they are forced to implement it with the correct parameters.

It still doesn't prevent people from creating an own constructor with obligatory parameters. This would still prevent their class from working in the context of your framework. But the presence of a method "initialize" they must implement is a pretty broad hint that this is where their initialization should actually take place and that these are the parameters that contain the information that is available to them at initialization.

Answer (score 1):

It is *not possible* to enforce a constructor signature. In this case it is better not to couple the classes by the relation of inheritance but to **create an interface** and work with objects on the interface level, what is also considered a good practice in object oriented design. In this case any classes added in the future would have to implement the interface and thus the contract will be enforced.

You can define in an interface some method, say `initialize`, with necessary signature. After you create an object, which must implement this interface (in this case the constructor ifself would not matter in sense that it won't be responsible for proper object construction from business point of view), just invoke on the created object this `initialize` method with necessary parameters, which would do the necessary object preparation routine.

Another possibility is before dynamic object instantiation to get the **constructor signature** by using RTTI and to check if necessary parameters are available and the instantiation would make sense. A sample coding:

```
DATA(l_class_name) = 'ZCL_XXX'.

DATA(lt_methods) = CAST cl_abap_classdescr( 
    cl_abap_classdescr=>describe_by_name( l_class_name ) 
)->methods.

DATA(lt_const_params) = lt_methods[ name = 'CONSTRUCTOR' ]-parameters.
```

The `lt_const_params` internal table with constructor parameters has the following structure:

```
length        type   i,
decimals      type   i,
type_kind     type   abap_typekind,
name          type   abap_parmname,
parm_kind     type   abap_parmkind,
by_value      type   abap_bool,
is_optional   type   abap_bool
```

Comment: Yes but the question remains: how to instantiate those classes dynamically in a consistent way ?

Comment: @Cutter by making the static create-method a part of the interface each of those classes has to implement.

Comment: The problem with static methods is that they cannot be redefined in sub-classes. If I ever need a sub-class, I won't be able to instantiate it because the create method would only instantiate the base class. This is not a factory method in the sense that it does not contain a logic for sub-class selection.

Comment: You can define in an interface some method, say "initialize", with necessary signature. After you create an object, which must implement this interface (in this case the constructor ifself would not matter in sense that it won't be responsible for proper object construction from business point of view), just invoke on the created object this "initialize" method with necessary parameters, which would do the necessary object preparation routine.

Comment: The instantiation would still be have to be dynamic. I need dynamic instantiation because the sub-class selection logic is dynamic. Not the initialization.

Comment: Yes, I mean dynamic instantiation. You dynamically select the class and dynamically instantiate the object, but after the instanation as a second step call the defined interface method with necessary paremeters. As you cannot enforce the constructor signature itself, shift the contract enforcement on the interface method. Maybe this strategory would help in your situation.

Comment: That does not solve the problem: if a subclass defines its own constructor signature, dynamic instantiation will fail.

Comment: Yes, but you cannot avoid it. In this case you can wrap the instantiation in try block, catch the exception and process it accordingly.

One more possibility I have added to the answer.